# Android Studio Showing squares instead of text

Tags: android-studio, debian

I have a HP Pro tower pre-installed with FreeLnx. Every application renders text correctly. However, each time I launch Android Studio it just shows a bunch of squares instead of text characters thus making it impossible to use the application. The debian version is squeeze and GNOME 2.30.2. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: his is a snap shot of what is displayed.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply changed my system font to FreeSans after which I launched Android Studio *poof* everything started working all fine.